# How to capture good sound with Arduino?

Tags: sound, adc

Is it possible to capture good sound with Aduino? I need to record street / birds / nature sounds.

[As I found](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/701/6841), maximal sample rate, achievable with built-in ADC is 9kHz, which is to low.

So, I require to use some external hardware. But wave shields I saw are to expensive (comparable by price with Arduino itself), probably, because of excess functions (including not only ADC but also DAC and so on).

Simultaneously, there are ICs, providing ADC functionality and even MP3 encoding functionality for relatively low price. But here a schematic design required.

So, how to find appropriate solution here?

Comment: I would use something with considerably more grunt than a baby Arduino - something with an I2S interface built in. Maybe a Due, but the best one that I use regularly would be a PIC32MZ based system, like the chipKIT WiFire.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but you want something much faster then the Arduino, normally it is in the 96k~48k bps range.  Try this link, they make a lot of great parts and the bulk of what you have to do is control software.  You can let the chip do the grunt work (analog) and transfer thee data to where ever you want.  Some of the chips will record for 300 seconds plus.

http://www.aplusinc.com.tw/exec/product.php?lg=E&mod=show&cid=43&pid=aPR33A3

I have used there parts they work great.

Have fun,
Gil

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to capture good sound with Aduino? I need to record street / birds / nature sounds.

The answer is "no" for AVR based Arduino boards. They have simply too low sampling rate, ADC resolution, limited buffering memory and processing speed.

The ADC sample rate is at most 9 K samples per second (112 us per sample) at highest resolution (10 bits). The resolution can be improved (e.g. 12 bits) by using [oversampling](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc8003.pdf) but this is at the cost of sampling frequency.

The Arduino Uno has only 2K byte memory. Using all that for buffering would give at most 1 K samples. That is little over a second sound data. A SD file could be used but requires a lot of smart programming to not drop samples at max sampling rate.

Low quality, 8-bit samples, then "yes". See [here](http://apcmag.com/arduino-projects-digital-audio-recorder.htm/).

Now an Arduino Due is much more powerful, has much more memory, etc. See [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SimpleAudioPlayer).

Comment: Is it possible to capture sound with Due?

Comment: Added some results from google. See new links above.

Comment: This about playing audio, but how about recording? How fast is DAC in Due?