# 3 AC current sensors using one Arduino Uno board measuring at 200Hz

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, datalogging

I'm new to electronics and need some help please.

I'm planning to measure current of a 3-phase output using one sensor for each phase (thus 3 sensors would be required). The frequency of data recording should be 200 Hz.

Performance/data transfer wise: Is one Arduino Uno board enough to plug in the three sensors and get the data transferred using the USB cable onto a PC? Or should I get one board for each sensor?

I appreciate your help.

Cheers.

lorena

Comment: what is the voltage ? If it is less than 5 volt you can use the internal interupts, the uno board have 3 such interupts

Comment: See Arduino Stackexchange https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/699/how-do-i-know-the-sampling-frequency

Comment: You also asked the question with the EmonLib: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/45353/setting-reading-frequency-sct013-current-sensor-code-using-arduino-uno Please explain what you want to achieve and why you need 200 samples per second for a 50Hz or 60Hz signal.

Answer (score 1):

1. Is the sampling speed enough?

It takes about 100 microseconds (0.0001 s) to read an analog input, so the maximum reading rate is about 10,000 times a second.

Ref.: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogRead

2. Is the USB port fast enough?

The serial speed over USB is maximum 2Mbps and a fast calculation (200 samples/s x 3 sensors x 10 bit) 18kbps, so 2Mbps should be enough.